# rhino runs javascript slowly on android phone

Tags: android, optimization, rhino

I hava complexed javascript files with more than one function.

When I run it on my mac, It takes about 8S with 1000 repeats. 
however when turns to android ,it takes more than 3 seconds to execute 1 time.

Is there any way to optimize on android?

I use evaluateString() to load the javascript content.

Comment: We need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry, i can't give a MCVE right now。Is there any way to optimize globally ?